# HTML Prototyping using Server Side Include (SSI) and Maven

Tags: html, maven, ssi, prototyping

When developing static HTML and JavaScript an Apache webserver is often used to play around with the JavaScript. I'm wondering if someone tried to use SSI for defining and assembling components when developing static HTML-Prototypes.

e.g. `<!--#include virtual="/footer.html" -->`

To deliver the artifacts to a client it is required that the includes become resolved like the way it is done by the webserver.

Since our build process is based on Maven I'm looking for a way/plugin to resolve the includes during packaging phase.

Comment: I have this exact same need and I'm still investigating... I'll update here if I have any clue

Comment: I'm wondering the same...